# Howto print Long in Binary?

Tags: java

I am trying to print a Long in Binary, but it keeps cutting off `0`'s. Is there a way to force it to show all bits?

This is my code:

```
long l = 1;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString((long)l));
```

Returns as mentioned only `1` due to removed `0`'s i wish to maintain:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

Thanks in advance.

My temporary nasty solution:

```
public String fillZeros(Long value) 
{
    String str = Long.toBinaryString((long) value);
    String temp;
    temp = str;
    while(temp.length() < 32) {
        temp = "0" + temp;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a long to a fixed-length 16-bit binary string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621017/how-to-convert-a-long-to-a-fixed-length-16-bit-binary-string)

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421438/986169

Comment: Do not ever use lower case L as a variable name.

Comment: At least use a `StringBuilder` because concatenating "0" repeatedly is inefficient. And you're supposed to append up to 64 zeroes, not 32.

Comment: @Tudor, thats not entirely true. It depends on if were speaking of `long` in terms of Java or C. Im working with C datatypes, as im only testing on Java. In terms of C `long` is 32-bit and `long long` is 64-bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do this

```
for(int i = 0; i < Long.numberOfLeadingZeros((long)l); i++) {
      System.out.print('0');
}
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString((long)l));
```

That will get what you want except without the spaces between every 4 numbers (you should be able to code that though). There might be a way to do this automatically with a [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
but I couldn't find it.

Edit:

you can use `String's` format method if you know the number of 0's you need (I forgot to change it back into a number this will fix the Exception).

```
String.format("%032d", new BigInteger(Long.toBinaryString((long)l)));
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

Comment: @JavaCake Fixed the exception

Comment: Also I used 32 because that's how many bits you had in your question but a Long in java is 64 bits so it really should be `"%064d"`

Comment: That did the trick. I mentioned why im using 32-bit in a comment on the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pull in Apache Commons StringUtil, you can do this:

```
    long l = 1;
    System.out.println( StringUtils.leftPad( Long.toBinaryString( l ), 64, "0" ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately im not using StringUtil.

Comment: StringUtil has a bunch of other useful stuff, I'd suggest considering adding it to your toolset in general. Unless this is a homework assignment sort of item.

Answer (score -1):

```
long value=4;
String mask = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
String str = Long.toBinaryString((long) value);
System.out.println(mask.substring(0, mask.length()-str.length())+str);

For a value of 4 the result will be 00000000000000000000000000000100
```

Comment: Simplest way I know.