# Printing long with a bit sequence

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, chess

Right now, I am working on a chess engine, which stores each different representations of the board in 64bits, which I store in a long variable. Example:

```
private long wKing = 0b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000;
```

The problem is, I am when I go to print it out, I instead am given the value on the bit sequence(8), not the actual sequence. Here is my print statement:

```
System.out.println(wKing);
```

How can I print this out so that it gives me the sequence instead, so i can use it for testing and printing out a representation of the board in the future? Thank you.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(wKing));` ? Also this might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401263/howto-print-long-in-binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Long.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString-long-).

`System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(wKing));`