# Java, print a short as binary with all 16 bits

Tags: java, binary, numbers, short

For example:

10 -> 0000 0000 0000 1010
15 -> 0000 0000 0000 1111

I tried using `Integer.toBinaryString()` but that prints

10 -> 1010
15 -> 1111

Is there a function that can print the short with all 16 digits or do I have to write my own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pad the left side with 0s:

```
int x=10;//or whatever
String.format("%016d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending manual 0's may help

```
String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(1)).replace(' ', '0')
```

will generate `0000000000000001`

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the following trick to display leading `zero/s`. For more detail look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621017/how-to-convert-a-long-to-a-fixed-length-16-bit-binary-string).

```
int displayMask = 1 << (size - 1);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer( size);
for ( int c = 1; c <= size; c++ ) 
{
    buf.append( ( value & displayMask ) == 0 ? '0' : '1' );
    value <<= 1;
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621017/how-to-convert-a-long-to-a-fixed-length-16-bit-binary-string/2621164#2621164) `Integer.toBinaryString()` leading `zeros` only for Integer/int. It will not work for `byte`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format()` to add padding before your result. The padding must be spaces, because `Integer.toBinaryString()` returns a `String`. Then all you need to do is replace the spaces with zeros (`0`) and split every nibble (fourth bit).

```
import java.util.*;

public class BinaryNumberPrinter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 10, 15 };

    for (int number : numbers) {
      String binaryValue = join(splitEveryFour(toShortBinary(number)), " ");
      System.out.printf("%d -> %s%n", number, binaryValue);
    }
  }

  public static String toShortBinary(int value) {
    return String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(value)).replace(' ', '0');
  }

  public static List<String> splitEveryFour(String value) {
    return Arrays.asList(value.split("(?<=\\G....)"));
  }

  public static String join(Iterable<? extends CharSequence> s, String delimiter) {
    Iterator<? extends CharSequence> iter = s.iterator();
    if (!iter.hasNext()) return "";
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(iter.next());
    while (iter.hasNext()) buff.append(delimiter).append(iter.next());
    return buff.toString();
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
10 -> 0000 0000 0000 1010
15 -> 0000 0000 0000 1111
```